# TS: Override Existing React Components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, overriding

I want to experiment with my existing component by rewriting it in an overrides template.

*Read here:* https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-override-existing-react-components

When I try to type the getComponents function, typescript fails to correctly recognize the return types. How to correctly type the returned value?

````
/**
 * @example
 *  ```
 *      const defaultComponents = { Root: ReactElement, Input: ReactElement };
 *      const overrides = { Input: { props: {'aria-label': 'Search product'}, }, };
 *
 *      getComponents(defaultComponents, overrides);
 *  ```
 */
export const getComponents = <T extends DefaultComponents>(
  defaultComponents: T,
  overrides: Override<T>
) => ...
````

[CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-moon-0yf39?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Why use `T extends infer R ...` instead of `{ [key: string]: ComponentType<...>}` since in the the `getComponents` function you will be accesing `overrides` with a string?

Comment: @J.Pichardo I created an example and attached it to the question, thanks for the response, I think I was thinking on the wrong side initially. https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-moon-0yf39?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I checked the example link and I don't see what your issue is, besides not having a return statement in the `getComponents` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the type on the overrides variable `Overrides<DefaultComponents>`

```
const defaultComponents = { Root: ReactElement, Input: ReactElement };

const overrides: Overrides<DefaultComponents> = { Input: { props: {'aria-label': 'Search product'}, }, };

getComponents(defaultComponents, overrides);
```